# Code for to Click on Customer textblock in telerik test studio

Tags: testing, frameworks, telerik, telerik-test-studio

How can I manually write code to click on a customer text block in Telerik Test Studio?  If I click on the customer, it displays to add new record text block. When I am recording and playback Telerik Test Studio, it's failing the click event.

Comment: Can you post your code, and describe exactly what is failing?

Answer (score 1):

By default, test studio doesn't trigger the appropriate javascript events to make dynamic web pages update correctly; but, there are a number of workarounds you can try. Which one you need depends on exactly which javascript event needs to be triggered and what needs to be happen, but I'd suggest trying the following:

- Edit the click step, enabling the 'SimulateRealClick' property:
  [image: eSimulateRealClick]
- Add an extra step to deliberately invoke the OnBlur event:
  [image: Invoke 'OnBlur' event]
- Add an extra step to deliberately invoke the OnChange event:
  [image]

In any case, it's worth talking to your developers to find out exactly what kind of event they're using to add the new record text block; that way you'll understand what kind of workaround is most suitable.